# Problema con el icono de una ventana en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy aprendiendo python y tengo este simple código, mi problema es que quiero cargar un icono para que aparezca en mi ventana y no lo carga al momento de ejecutar la ventana, las dimensiones del icono son de 28x29 y lo tengo en la misma carpeta donde esta guardado el programa.

```py
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Prueba")

raiz.resizable(0,0)

raiz.iconbitmap("fox.ico")

raiz.geometry("650x350")

raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que lo tengas en la carpeta desde donde ejecutas el programa no desde donde tienes el programa

ademas si estas en linux no funciona el formato .ico tienes que usar .gif o bmp

Comment: Estoy en windows 10 y si tengo la imagen desde donde se ejecuta el programa, en anteriores actividades ya había realizado el cargar una imagen desde la carpeta donde tengo alojado el programa y  no había tenido problemas, hasta ahora.

Comment: puede que sea la imagen,has probado con otro icono?

Comment: Ya utilice diferentes iconos y aun así no me marca error en la ejecución pero no carga el icono en cualquiera que intento

Answer (score 0):

No encuentra la ruta definida del archivo que intentas cargar.

A veces se presenta este error porque el interprete no encuentra el archivo aunque esté en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable.

Para solucionarlo coloca `r` seguido del nombre de la carpeta y el archivo donde se encuentra, algo así:

```
raiz.iconbitmap(r"nombre_carpeta/fox.ico")
```